# First-order linear matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose we are given the following matrix differential equation in $X \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

$$ \dot{X} (t) = AX(t) + X(t)A^{T} + M(t) $$

where $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is given and the initial condition for is $X(t_0) =: X_0$. Find a solution $X(t)$.

---

How can I approach this problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

If there were no $M(t)$ term, then the solution would be

$$X(t) = \Phi(t,t_0)X_0\Phi(t,t_0)^{T}$$

Indeed, this solution satisfies the both differential equation and the initial condition. I could not understand how $M(t)$ affects the solution?

For example, if I could write the solution like

$$ X(t) = \Phi(t,t_0)X $$

then solution for $\dot{X} = AX(t) + M(t)$ would be

$$ X(t) = \Phi(t,t_0)X_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t}\Phi(t,\tau)M(\tau)d\tau $$

Comment: When working with matrices and vectors a common convention is to use capital roman/greek letters for matrices, lowercase roman letters for vectors and lowercase greek/roman letters for scalars. I'd recommend you to follow this convention.

Comment: If you [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides, would you be able to solve the (forced) linear ODE?

Comment: This [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353051) may help.

Comment: Thanks @greg. The particular solution will be $\int_{t_0}^{t}\Phi(t,\tau)M(\tau)\Phi(t,\tau)^Td\tau$ then. Is this right?

Comment: Why use the general state-transition function instead of the matrix exponential?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yeah sorry, $\Phi(t,\tau)$ should be $e^{A(t-\tau)}$